# BeautifoulSoup not working on malformed utf-8 HTML

Tags: python, html, utf-8, beautifulsoup, malformed

I'm starting to play with `BeautifulSoup` but its not working. Just tried to obtain all links with `find_all('a')` and the reponse is always `[]` or `null`. Issues could be caused by iso/utf-8 encoding or malformed html, right?

I've found that if I only take code between `<body></body>` tags it will work ok, so we can prob discard encoding.

So what to do? Is there a soup built-in function to fix malformed html? Maybe use RE to just take `<body>` contents? Any clues? Its probably a common issue...

By the way, i'm dealing with Portuguese (pt_BR) language, Win64, Python27 and example not-working page is http://www.tudogostoso.com.br/

EDIT: What i've done so far

```
#im using mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
site = 'http://www.tudogostoso.com.br/'
r = br.open(site)

#returned html IS OK. outputed and tested a lot
html = r.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']

#nothing happens
#but if html = <body>...</body> (cropped manually) its works and prints all the links
```

Comment: You should probably show what you've tried so far.

Comment: how did you get the `html`? what type of object is it?

Comment: edited with `html` getting details. im using `mechanize`. the returned `html` is ok. malformed but ok. ive checked a lot before making the question.

Comment: your code prints all the links, what exactly is is your issue?

Comment: You should get links with your code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham are you sure? its not printing here. full html is malformed. it only prints if I crop everything inside and including the tag `<body>...</body>`

Comment: Do you have `lxml` or `html5lib` installed?

Comment: no @alecxe. should i?

Comment: Following up on @alecxe, read [Specifying the parser to use](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) in the BS docs. BS can only do so much with malformed tags if the parser is choking on them before they get to it.

Comment: finally a good and consistent answer! thank you

Comment: `BeautifulSoup(markup, "html5lib")` just did it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to `@abarnert`

`html5lib` can deal with malformations. Also, `HTML5` has some new peculiaritys that may look malformations to a human like me or even to an older parser, like the one `BeautifulSoup` uses as default. They are not really malformations.

So, at the end, using

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html5lib")
```

instead of just

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

just did it!

Answer (score -1):

For downloading page use some module lie [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) or [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html).

`Requests` module:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://www.tudogostoso.com.br/')
html = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

`urllib2`:

```
import urllib2
r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.tudogostoso.com.br/')
html = r.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", a['href']
```

Comment: the output is exactly the same as that from the  OP's code

Comment: Sorry but none worked. As i said: the `html` string is FINE. Tried fetching with `requests`, `urllib2` and `mechanize`. The problem is original page code malformation. How to deal with it?

Comment: @Sarchophagi what is `original page code malformation`? what is your expected output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham OP did not posted the full code first. and from his question i assume  he is trying to get the same output my code and his code is giving.

Comment: Original server-side code is malformed. Like it has unbalanced tags and/or brackets. The malformation is not coming from bad url fetching. Expecting links while not having to crop `<body>` contents. Why you guys are downvoting this perfectly valid question SO HARD?

Comment: @Sarchophagi I see you got the solution :). Your question was not a perfectly valid question. it was misleading at first. you should have posted your code snippet on earlier edits.